# Calling mmap twice for a file

Tags: large-files, mmap

I want to reach parts of a large file randomly. After opening the part I needed with mmap if I need another part of the file. Should I close the first memory mapped region and mmap again or can I open two memory mapped region at the same time?

I don't want to map all the file since it could be larger than the RAM and I will use multiple files open at the same time on my program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mmapping does not consume RAM. You can and should map the entire file unless it is larger than the available *address space*. On a 64-bit computer, that's rather unlikely. On 32-bits, it's not impossible.

In any case, you can make as many mappings as you want of each single file.

Comment: I want to be able to open 20-30 number of files. On a 32-bits system If I open 2 4GB-files at the same time, will I be out of address space.?

Comment: On a 32-bit system can't map all of even one 4GB file. So make many little mappings of pieces, as per my second paragraph.